# Check array for length and push or update the object within

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm really struggling with my code and cannot find a way to make it work.

I need to check whether my array exists or its length is not 0 and then if there is an object with a specific value in it. If so then update it. If not then add it. Please see my code below:

```
const originals = [];

if (!originals || originals.length === 0) {
  originals.push({
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 21,
    "gender": "male"
  });
} else {
  for (i = 0; i < originals.length; i++) {
    if (originals[i].name !== "Michael") {
      originals.push({
        "name": "Michael",
        "age": 21,
        "gender": "male"
      });
    }
    if (originals[i].name == "Michael" && originals[i].age == 21) {
      originals[i].age = 22;
    }
  }
  console.log(originals);
}
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What's with Samantha? That code doesn't really correspond to your problem description. It seems you try to do different updates in the same code. Maybe focus your question on one thing only...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you. Let me simplify the array. So it is easier to understand.

Comment: So, what is the logic with the age? So you want to *both* add with age 21, and then detect it is 21 and make it 22? Your description mentions nothing about this logic.

Comment: Hi @trincot thank you. I am trying to create an array or check the existing one with objects. If there is an object with name and age then update it, if not then push it as a new object. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So there can be more than one entry with the same name, as long as they have different age? And what is the logic of the age update? You only want to be able to detect 21-year olds? Why is it hard-coded? Can you please edit your question with a full description of the logic? What if you want to update the age by adding 5?

Comment: You can't know if the object with that name exists until the end of the loop. You're pushing the new element for every element that doesn't match the criteria, not just if it's not anywhere in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and time guys! Really helpful. I think I found my issue so will update the question with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `find()` method to look for an element with the name you want. If it's found, update it, otherwise add the new element.

There's no need to check the length of the array. If the array is empty, `find()` won't find it.

```
let mike = originals.find(({name}) => name == 'Michael');
if (mike) {
    if (mike.age == 21) {
        mike.age = 22;
    }
} else {
    originals.push({
        "name": "Michael",
        "age": 21,
        "gender": "male"
    });
}
```

This solution assumes names are unique. If there can be multiple `Michael` entries, you can use `filter()` instead of `find()` to return all of them.

Comment: Nit: You could make `mike` a `const`. :-)

Comment: Very simple and effective way to achieve my goal with a few lines of code. Thank you @barmar

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines what I think you want to do is:

- If "Michael" is in the array. Then his age should be updated to 21, if he is 22 years old.
- If "Michael" is not in the array. Then add Michael with an age of 21.

There are some odd things in your code which makes no sense to me. For example you are checking for "Michael" in the array each time when iterating the array. This would mean that you insert a "Michael" for each entry that is not named "Michael". That doesn't make sense, does it?

I think this is what you want:

```js
function addOrUpdateMichael(array) {
  const michael = array.find((x) => x.name == "Michael");
  if (!michael) {
      array.push({
          "name": "Michael",
          "age": 21,
          "gender": "male"
      });
  } else if (michael.age == 22) {
      michael.age = 21;
  }
  return array;
}

const testArray1 = [];
console.log(addOrUpdateMichael(testArray1));

const testArray2 = [{
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 21,
    "gender": "male"
}, {
    "name": "Tony",
    "age": 18,
    "gender": "male"
}];
console.log(addOrUpdateMichael(testArray2));

const testArray3 = [{
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 22,
    "gender": "male"
}, {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 36,
    "gender": "male"
}];
console.log(addOrUpdateMichael(testArray3));
```

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: Why use `findIndex` instead of `find`?

Comment: @Barmar well it's not a difference for the result, but I do agree that using `find` makes the code more readable. Updated the answer. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick solution to this issue:

From my perspective its a good idea to address a new array to contain temporary data.

The easiest way to describe what I mean follows in the code snippet.

### Code Snippet (For-Loop)

```
var originalsStack=[];


function PushToOriginalStack() {

for (i=0; i < originals.length; i++) {
    if (originals[i].name != "Samantha") {
        originalsStack.push({
            "name": "Michael",
            "age": 21,
            "gender": "male"
        });

    }
    else if (originals[i].name == "Samantha" && originals[i].age == 20) {
        originals[i].age = 21;
        originalsStack.push(originals[i]);
    }


    console.log(i);
}

originals = originalsStack;
}

PushToOriginalStack();

console.log(originals);
```

Important keep your Data handy, so you can handle the originals array.
Hope I could help a bit! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is below with help of amazing supporters on StackOverflow. Thank you all

```js
const originals = [{
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 21,
    "gender": "male"
}];
if (!originals || originals.length === 0) {
    originals.push({
        "name": "Michael",
        "age": 21,
        "gender": "male"
    });
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < originals.length; i++) {
        if (originals[i].name !== "Michaels") {
            originals.push({
                "name": "Michaels",
                "age": 22,
                "gender": "male"
            });
        }
        if (originals[i].name == "Michael" && originals[i].age == 21) {
            originals[i].age = 24;
        }
    }
}
console.log(originals);
```

Comment: Please clean up your indentation.

Comment: What's the difference from the original code, other than setting the age to 24 instead of 22?

Comment: If `originals` isn't set, `originals.push()` will get an error.

Comment: This has the same problem as the old code. It will add a new Michaels entry for every non-Michaels entry.

Comment: Hi @Barmar it was a few typos and also advice from other people helped to re-code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the name you're looking for `Michael` or `Michaels`?

Comment: Look at the result in your snippet, is that really what you wanted to get?